# How to submit form data to express server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

I have set up a basic express server to accept some information submitted through a form. Unfortunately, I have run into some problems.
I cannot log the data I receive onto the console. Can someone please help me figure this out?

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use('/',(req,res,next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public','index.html'));
});

app.post('/api', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}!`))
```

And here's the form itself:
index.html:

```
   <body>
      <h1>Hello there!</h1>
      <form id='form' method="POST" action="/api">
         <input id='textField' type='text' name='name' placeholder='Enter your name'>
         <p>Enter your date of birth:</p>
         <div class='dob'>
            <input id='date' type='number' name='date' placeholder='Date'>
            <select id='dobMonth' name="month">
               <option value="default">Month</option>
               <option value="Jan">January</option>
               <option value="Feb">February</option>
               <option value="Mar">March</option>
               <option value="April">April</option>
               <option value="May">May</option>
               <option value="June">June</option>
               <option value="July">July</option>
               <option value="Aug">August</option>
               <option value="Sept">Septmeber</option>
               <option value="Oct">October</option>
               <option value="Nov">November</option>
               <option value="Dec">December</option>
            </select>
            <input id='year' type='number' name='year' placeholder='Year'>
         </div>
         <input id='btn' type='submit'>
      </form>
      <script src='script.js'></script>
   </body>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you submitting the form normally or using AJAX?

Comment: The form is being submitted normally. I did try to use fetch API. But none of these worked successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is just the order of your routes. The first path you specify:

```
app.use('/',(req,res,next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public','index.html'));
});
```

Is acting as a catch-all, since every path on the server includes '/'

If you switch the order and make the catch-all last, this should work just fine for you.

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
})

app.use('/',(req,res,next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public','index.html'));
});
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you very much.

I also tried adding next() to the function, which also does the job. Not sure which one is the proper way.

Comment: What is the `path` value?

Comment: `path` in this snippet is a javascript library used for building file paths:
https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Here it is used to join the environment variable `__dirname` with the directory `public` and filename `index.html` to make something like `/Users/foo/src/myrepo/public/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you need [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware and tnen you can get parsed data from request:

here is simple example:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})

// POST /api/users gets JSON bodies
app.post('/api/users', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  // create user in req.body
})
```

But it's does not handle multipart bodies (post with files).
Due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

- [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme)
- [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme)
- [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem because instead of using the bodyParser package from npm I'm using a similar middleware that comes out of the box express.js.

Comment: @DebabrataMondal, so first try with package, for example `formidable` and if work with package, then you can try parse raw request, just using only js. 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable it's easy and fast package

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form class="innerWidth" action="/contact-detail/"  method="post">
   <label for="">Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <label for="">Business Email</label>
   <input type="email" name="email"  >
   <label for="">Role</label>
   <input type="text" name="role">
   <label for="">Contact No.</label>
   <input class="contactInput"  type="text"  name="number" >
   <label for="">Message</label>
   <input class="messageInput" type="text"  name="message"  >
   <div class="submitBtn">
      <input  type="submit" value="Submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

```js
app.post('/contact-detail/', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
    // create user in req.body
})
```